# Convert XOR function to return char* not string

Tags: c++, xor

I coded this XOR using string but I need to return a char* now. I've been trying to do this for hours, though I'm not really used to work with char. I guess I'm missing something here.

```
string XOR(string s, int key){

 string res = "";

 for (size_t temp = 0; temp < s.size(); ++temp){
  res += s[temp] ^ ((key + temp) % 255);
 }
 return res;

}
```

How could I change this to get a char* in return?

Edited to clarify: I need a char* : char* XOR(string s, int key)

Comment: Why do you mean by "to get a char in return" ? C style string ?

Comment: Please show a suggested signature of the method you wish to create.

Comment: From the returned `string` you can call `c_str()` to get a `const char*`.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you mean by "return a char". As stated, you're asking how to return a single character value. I doubt that that's what you mean, and if it is, you'll need to tell us how you want that `char` value to be determined.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't think you can do that within this function though, since `res` will just get popped off the stack.

Comment: @PeterWood: If the string is on the stack (as it is here), the `const char *` you get back from `c_str()` will be invalid the moment the function returns.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Sorry, I meant that the function shouldn't be changed at all. If user2177904 needs a character string they can get already get it from the returned string. They shouldn't change the function to just return `c_str()` instead, as there are lifetime issues once the function scope ends.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: it was buged, but corrected with help of @JonathanGrynspan and @john, and now my final version is:

I know this is not beautiful but it does what you want:

```
char* XOR(string s, int key){
 string res = "";
 for (size_t temp = 0; temp < s.size(); ++temp){
  res += s[temp] ^ ((key + temp) % 255);
 }
 char * cstr = new char [res.length()+1];
 copy(res.begin(),res.end(),cstr);
 return cstr;
}
```

Comment: Any attempt to use the result of this function will crash because the owner of the memory at the returned address is destroyed before the function finishes returning.

Comment: sorry @Jonathan Grynspan, it is not true, I have tried and it works. have you tried?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan please refer to this

Comment: I misread your post and missed the `new` operator. This is still wrong because you will leak the `std::string` that you created with `new`.

Comment: You return a pointer to `s_ptr->c_str()` which is *not* the same as `s_ptr`. The caller then has a C string he can't safely free, and a leaked `std::string` that he can't find.

Comment: if this is not the same, why then caller can't safely free it?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan please see my EDIT, is this OK now?

Comment: No, now we're back to the original problem of returning a pointer that becomes invalid when the function ends.

Comment: And the caller can't safely free the C string because it is owned by the C++ string and you don't know how it was allocated, so you don't know how to free it.

Comment: isn't now std::string destroyed when function returns? and function returns just copy of string (as const char* casted to char*)? note it works: there is no errors and if there is no leaks must be then OK

Comment: The function only returns a copy of the C++ string *if you're returning the C++ string*.

Comment: It's bugged. s_ptr is destroyed on exit from the function, that frees the memory you are returning a pointer to. Just because 'it works' does not mean it's correct.

Comment: @john omg please run the function first then vote and comment, I know it is not OK, but certainly it is not true what you said

Comment: @cf16: The function is broken as written. Your arguments to the contrary do not make it correct.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan can you please explain me, where is memory leak now?

Comment: @ct16 There is no leak now. Now you have memory being used after being freed. That's not a leak, it's heap corruption.

Comment: @john I run this function now, at this moment and get no errors

Comment: @cf16. As i said, just because it works doesn't mean it's not bugged. It's worrying that you are working in finance as a C++ programer and you don't seem to understand the basics.

Comment: I run this code: string resp4=XOR(es,4);
    cout<<resp4;
    string resp3=XOR(es,3);
    cout<<resp3;

Comment: @cf16 Right now there is no leak, there is *undefined behaviour*. The returned pointer is to invalid memory. That it doesn't crash is not indicative of correct functionality, and on another system or with other input or at another time of day it can and will crash.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan maybe now, is this OK?

Comment: Actually, it's still wrong. `strcpy()` is unsafe and should not be used (your compiler will probably warn you about it.) In this trivial case it's okay, but you should probably replace it with `std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), cstr);`.

Comment: yes, I know it is deprecated, but in this example when I know what I copy it is OK, but I have changed this as you suggested

Comment: @john and apologies since you were right, I just thought something else

Answer (score 1):

Is your input string overwritable? If so, this is the easiest and probably fastest method:

```
void XOR( char *input, int key ){
    for(int temp = 0; input[temp] != '\0'; ++temp){
        input[temp] ^= (key + temp) % 255;
    }
}
```

It changes the given string instead of returning something new. But since there's every chance you'll get `\0` characters in the output, you might find this more reliable:

```
void XOR( char *input, int key, int length ){
    for(int temp = 0; temp < length; ++temp){
        input[temp] ^= (key + temp) % 255;
    }
}
```

(obviously the length isn't changed)

Update:

After seeing the comments, maybe this is what you want. But be *careful* with it; you will need to remember to free the memory returned, which isn't something C++-only programmers are used to;

```
char *XOR( const string &s, int key ) {
    const std::size_t l = s.size( );
    char *r = (char *) malloc( (l + 1) * sizeof( char ) );
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < l; ++ i ) {
        r[i] = s[i] ^ ((key + (int) i) % 255)
    }
    r[l] = '\0'; // only needed if you need a null-capped string, which seems unlikely since your string could well contain nulls anyway
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to give the length. Actually I need a char* not a char so the signature of the function I'm trying to do is char* XORED(string s, int key);
I've tried to get a const char* with c_str() and I failed.. But I guess there's a better way to do it

Comment: @user2177904 see updated answer. I think the final code is what you want.